# error 401 when I send requests

Tags: angularjs, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I use symfony in backend and angular js 1.6 in frontend for authentification but now I have bug when I send requests I have bug status 401 (Invalid credentials) .. I use jwtauthentificationBundle for generate token .. I add token in localStorage and interceptors but when I clicked in any button in page you lunched service Interceptors ...

config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@MedBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    secret:          "%secret%"
    csrf_protection: ~
    form: ~
    session:
        handler_id: ~
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "test@test.com"
        sender_name: "Demo String"
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift

lexik_jwt_authentication:
    private_key_path: %jwt_private_key_path%
    public_key_path:  %jwt_public_key_path%
    pass_phrase:      %jwt_key_pass_phrase%
    token_ttl:        %jwt_token_ttl%

nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_origin:   ["%cors_allow_origin%"]
        allow_methods:  ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
        allow_headers:  ["content-type", "authorization"]
        expose_headers: ["link"]
        max_age:       3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }

fos_rest:
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
            - { path: '^/', stop: true }
```

security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            lexik_jwt:
                authorization_header:
                    enabled: true
                    prefix: Bearer
                query_parameter:
                    enabled: true
                    name: bearer
                throw_exceptions: false
                create_entry_point: true

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: fos_userbundle
            stateless: true
            form_login: 
                check_path: /login_check
                username_parameter: _username
                password_parameter: _password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false
            logout: true
            anonymous: true


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute","ngStorage"]);

app.config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider', function($routeProvider,$httpProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/login", {
      templateUrl: Routing.generate('login',
        {template:"default/login.html.twig"}),
        controller: 'loginctrl',
    })
    .when("/register", {
      templateUrl: Routing.generate('register',
        {template:"default/registere.html.twig"}),
      controller: 'httpgetctrl',  
    })
    .when("/affiche", {
    templateUrl: Routing.generate('get',
        {template:"default/affiche.html.twig"}),
      controller: 'httpgetctrl',  
    });
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

}]);

    app.controller("httpgetctrl", function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.SendData = function () {
           // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON 
            var data = $.param({
                username: $scope.username,
                email: $scope.email,
                pass: $scope.password,
                confir: $scope.confirmationpass
            });

            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }

            $http.post(Routing.generate('register'), data, config)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("success");
            })
            .catch(function() {
                console.log("error");
  })
        };

    });

    app.controller("loginctrl", function ($scope, $http,$localStorage) {

        $scope.login = function () {
           // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON 
            var data = $.param({
                username: $scope.user,
                password: $scope.pass
            });

            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            }

            $http.post(Routing.generate('login'), data, config)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("success login");                
                localStorage.token = response.data['token'] ;
                console.log(localStorage.token);
            })
            .catch(function() {
                console.log("error login");
  })
        };

    });

  app.factory('authInterceptor', function($rootScope, $q, $window) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};

            if (localStorage.token) {
                //config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token;
                config.headers['x-access-token'] = localStorage.token;
                console.log('done');
            }
            return config;
        },
        response: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                // if 401 unauthenticated
                console.log("error 401");
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
// call the factory ...
})
```

index.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %} Acceuil {% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #e74c3c;
        margin-right: 25px;

}

</style>

{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <a href="#/!">Acceuil</a>

<a href="#!login">Login</a>
<a href="#!register">Register</a> 
<a href="#!affiche">Affiche</a>
<br><br>

<div ng-view></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="angularJwt.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ngstorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/todc-bootstrap/3.3.7-3.3.13/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/app.js') }}"></script>

<script>



</script>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

and code controller:

```
<?php

namespace MedBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RouteResource;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\ViewHandler;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use MedBundle\Entity\Med;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\EventListener\JWTCreatedlistener;

 Class ApiController extends Controller {

    public function getAction() {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $test = $em->getRepository('MedBundle:Med')->findAll();
        //$viewHandler = $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler');

        // Création d'une vue FOSRestBundle
        //$view = View::create($test);
        //$view->setFormat('json');

        // Gestion de la réponse
        //return $viewHandler->handle($view);
        return array('test'=>$test);

    }


    public function loginAction() {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $test = null; $token = null; $res = 'null';
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $username = $request->request->get('username');
            $password = $request->request->get('password');

         $test = $em->getRepository('MedBundle:Med')->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));

            if (!($test)) { $res = "error"; } else{ 
                $salt= $test->getSalt();
                $pass = crypt($password,$salt);
                if ( $pass !== $test->getPassword() ) { $res='error password'; } else {
                $res='success';   

            $token = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager')->create($test);

            $test->setToken($token);
            $em->persist($test);
            $em->flush();

         } } 
         //return new Response($res);
         $test = [];
         $test['token'] = $token;
         $test['res'] = $res;
         return new JsonResponse($test);
 }    

            return $this->render('default/login.html.twig',array('test' => json_encode($test), 'token' => $token,'res' => json_encode($res)));

    }



    public function logoutAction() {



    }

 }
```

Comment: What does your post request look like can you add that to your question with all the headers you are sending

Comment: Also why is this line commented config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.token, as far as I know your server is expecting the jwt token in header with Bearer

Comment: I test with 2 lines but also error and with two lines I have in headers token with name Authorization or x-access-token .. for requests when I have 401 :action getAction() in ApiController.php .. when i click button 'affiche' I have this error and when I click in any button I have in console 'done' (console of service Interceptors )

Comment: Have a look at these tutorials http://knpuniversity.com/search?q=jwt it will tell you step by step how to setup authentication

Comment: now when I use public function getAction() {$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();$test = $em->getRepository('MedBundle:Med')->findAll();$token = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder')->encode(['username' => 'med']);
        return array('test'=>$test,'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token()]);} and error is "Attempted to call function "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im1lZCIsI.tPpNv31uAYZRypjnkgO2OkX6YFyGw8j92klCPl8WF7v7_KnZ-74728PBIOLeLaotJtu6k" from the global namespace."
 how to resolve this bug !!!